# Why won't Binary search find an element in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, binary-search

Why won't Binary Search find an element?

I have one array with elements: BBBB, BBBB, CCCC. I want to find elements BBBB and BBBB. I want binary search to find two elements and it finds one. The output is "1" and it should be "2".

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> bricks = new ArrayList<String>(List.of("BBBB","BBBB","CCCC"));
        ArrayList<String> bricksNeeded = new ArrayList<String>(List.of("BBBB","BBBB"));
        int nFound = 0;
        int index;
        for(String brickNeeded:bricksNeeded){
            index = Collections.binarySearch(bricks, brickNeeded);
            if(index >= 0){
                bricks.remove(bricks.get(index));
                nFound ++;
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(nFound);
    }
}
```

Output:
`1`

Expected output:
`2`

Comment: You break out of the loop if you find an element, so it stops looping *(hence it stops searching)*. Tangentially: if the list being searched is large *(for various values of "large")* instead of searching again it might make more sense to iterate backwards/forwards until a non-match, but for small-ish lists it's likely not a necessary optimization.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks, you're right. But what do you mean by "iterate backwards"? How can I do that?

Comment: You know the index of the found element. You can get previous indexes with subtraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have statement `break` - loop will be stopped after first removing.
So, `nFound` will be incremented only once

Comment: Minor quibble: `break` is a statement, not an operator.